# dialog menu to display files and select one of them

Tags: shell-script, files, dialog

I want to display all the files under `/home` directory in menu, and select only one of them. Then the script will print the full path of the selected file.

I have created the following script. This script only displays the files in the dialog box menu.

```
#!/bin/bash
dialog --title "List file of directory /home" --msgbox "$(ls /home )" 100 100
```

Comment: You are better off with fzf or ranger. fzf in particular can change your life.

Answer (score 7):

[dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) has file-selection and directory-selection widgets (like Xdialog):

[image: picture of dialog with --fselect]

To use it, OP's script might be

```
#!/bin/bash
dialog --title "List file of directory" --fselect /home 100 100
```

though a 100x100 window seems rather large.  The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h2-OPTIONS) provides better alternatives:

> Most widgets accept height and width parameters, which can be  used  to automatically  size the widget to accommodate multi-line message prompt values:
>
> - If the parameter is negative, dialog uses the screen's size.
> - If the parameter is zero, dialog uses minimum size for  the  widget to display the prompt and data.
> - Otherwise, dialog uses the given size for the widget.

If you want to limit yourself to scripts that could be run with `whiptail`, the `--radiolist` option is an alternative to `--menu`.

Comment: `tput cols` and `tput lines` might be handy to avoid the `Can't make new window at` error

Answer (score 5):

You should be using menu not message box.
Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
let i=0 # define counting variable
W=() # define working array
while read -r line; do # process file by file
    let i=$i+1
    W+=($i "$line")
done < <( ls -1 /home )
FILE=$(dialog --title "List file of directory /home" --menu "Chose one" 24 80 17 "${W[@]}" 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3) # show dialog and store output
RESULT=$?
clear
if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]; then # Exit with OK
     echo "${W[$((FILE * 2 -1))]}"
fi
```

Array is here necessary, otherwise it would not parse right as command, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Script is listing everything in /home folder, same as your example. If you really want only files, replace

```
ls -1 /home
```

with

```
find /home -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Also think about using 'whiptail', because it is default in most distributions. Dialog is not mostly installed.

Comment: what is the "realpath" ?? , second how to delete the a(+)  from the menu  ?  ( my script fail on line 11: realpath: command not found )

Comment: [realpath](http://linux.die.net/man/1/realpath) - return the canonicalised absolute pathname

Comment: a(+)? you mean that number? You can use whiptail and then simply '--notags'. I think that it is not possible with dialog.
As for realpath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284662/how-do-you-normalize-a-file-path-in-bash

Comment: I dont have realpath in my linux can you please use other syntax?  ( +1 for you )

Comment: Just replace `realpath` with `readlink -f`. Readlink is part of gnu coreutils so you must have it.